# youtube iframe on bootstrap gives full screen mode error

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, iframe, youtube, fullscreen

I have a youtube movie on a website in an iframe.

When I choose "full screen mode" on the youtube movie it takes the width of the bootstrap container instead off the fullscreen width and height.

It worked previously.

URL: 15815.be

Answer (score 1):

I found it,

It's the classes in the animate.css I added that conflict with the fullscreen mode of youtube.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that encounters this problem in the future, you have to update animate.css to the last version. There where a few conflicting names of classes which have been fixed at some point. Thanks to user user2740557 by the way.